# Find overlapping ranges by factor level using R

Tags: r

I need to find overlapping ranges within a single data set but need to find them for each ID or factor level. Any assistance would be appreciated!

```
    library(dplyr)

df_foo = read.table(
  textConnection("Class    Min  Max
A    500  630
A    100  200
B    100  200
A    210  310
A    200  210
B    210  310
A    510  530
B    200  210
A    705  800
B    500  630
B    510  530
B    705  800"), header = TRUE
)

c = outer(df_foo$Max, df_foo$Min, ">")
d = outer(df_foo$Min, df_foo$Max, "<")

df_foo %>% 
  mutate(Overlap = apply(c & d, 1, sum) > 1 
  )
```

The result I am getting is as follows:

```
   Class Min Max Overlap
1      A 500 630    TRUE
2      A 100 200    TRUE
3      B 100 200    TRUE
4      A 210 310    TRUE
5      A 200 210    TRUE
6      B 210 310    TRUE
7      A 510 530    TRUE
8      B 200 210    TRUE
9      A 705 800    TRUE
10     B 500 630    TRUE
11     B 510 530    TRUE
12     B 705 800    TRUE
```

But I want to find the overlaps between each level of A and B like this:

```
   Class Min Max Overlap
1      A 500 630    TRUE
2      A 100 200    FALSE
3      B 100 200    FALSE
4      A 210 310    FALSE
5      A 200 210    FALSE
6      B 210 310    FALSE
7      A 510 530    TRUE
8      B 200 210    FALSE
9      A 705 800    FALSE
10     B 500 630    TRUE
11     B 510 530    TRUE
12     B 705 800    FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other `data.table` approach.
The order of the sample data / ranges is irrelevant in this answer... `foverlaps()` does all the hard work for you.

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )
dt <- as.data.table( df_foo )
```

**code**

```
#set key for the data.table
setkey(dt, Min, Max)
#perform overlap join, keep only joined ranges where the class is the same, and Min and Max are not the same.
result <- foverlaps( dt, dt )[ Class == i.Class & !(Min == i.Min | Max == i.Max | Min == i.Max | Max == i.Min), ]
#create a logical vector (i.e. Overlap) by checking if the (pasted) combination of
#Class, Min and Max exists in both 'dt' and 'result'
dt[ , Overlap := paste0( Class, Min, Max ) %in% paste0( result$Class, result$Min, result$Max) ][]

#     Class Min Max Overlap
#  1:     A 100 200   FALSE
#  2:     B 100 200   FALSE
#  3:     A 200 210   FALSE
#  4:     B 200 210   FALSE
#  5:     A 210 310   FALSE
#  6:     B 210 310   FALSE
#  7:     A 500 630    TRUE
#  8:     B 500 630    TRUE
#  9:     A 510 530    TRUE
# 10:     B 510 530    TRUE
# 11:     A 705 800   FALSE
# 12:     B 705 800   FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the answer in `data.table`, the translation into `dplyr` should be straigtworfard. The idea is to create a vector of the previous cumulated maximum , per class :

```
df_foo <- setDT(df_foo)
df_foo[, shiftedmaxmax := c(NA,cummax(Max)[1:(.N-1)]),by = Class  ]


    Class Min Max shiftedmaxmax
 1:     A 100 200            NA
 2:     A 200 210           200
 3:     A 210 310           210
 4:     A 500 630           310
 5:     A 510 530           630
 6:     A 705 800           630
 7:     B 100 200            NA
 8:     B 200 210           200
 9:     B 210 310           210
10:     B 500 630           310
11:     B 510 530           630
12:     B 705 800           630
```

And to compare the minimum with the previous maximum of Maximum (so if it is inferior to this value, the current line is in the range of one previous line)

```
df_foo[,superposed := Min < shiftedmaxmax]

    Class Min Max shiftedmaxmax superposed
 1:     A 100 200            NA         NA
 2:     A 200 210           200      FALSE
 3:     A 210 310           210      FALSE
 4:     A 500 630           310      FALSE
 5:     A 510 530           630       TRUE
 6:     A 705 800           630      FALSE
 7:     B 100 200            NA         NA
 8:     B 200 210           200      FALSE
 9:     B 210 310           210      FALSE
10:     B 500 630           310      FALSE
11:     B 510 530           630       TRUE
12:     B 705 800           630      FALSE
```

The first superposed is missing, and you can get it this way:

```
df_foo[,superposedsource :=  Max %in% shiftedmaxmax[superposed],by = Class]
df_foo[,superposedtot := ifelse((superposed | superposedsource) &,T,F)]

    Class Min Max shiftedmaxmax superposed superposedsource superposedtot
 1:     A 100 200            NA         NA            FALSE            NA
 2:     A 200 210           200      FALSE            FALSE         FALSE
 3:     A 210 310           210      FALSE            FALSE         FALSE
 4:     A 500 630           310      FALSE             TRUE          TRUE
 5:     A 510 530           630       TRUE            FALSE          TRUE
 6:     A 705 800           630      FALSE            FALSE         FALSE
 7:     B 100 200            NA         NA            FALSE            NA
 8:     B 200 210           200      FALSE            FALSE         FALSE
 9:     B 210 310           210      FALSE            FALSE         FALSE
10:     B 500 630           310      FALSE             TRUE          TRUE
11:     B 510 530           630       TRUE            FALSE          TRUE
12:     B 705 800           630      FALSE            FALSE         FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the ranges are not in ascending or descending order. They are all mixed up. I have edited the data set to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

with `dplyr`

```
df=df_foo%>%group_by(Class)%>%
  mutate(Overlap=if_else(Min<lag(Max,order_by=Class),TRUE,FALSE))
df$Overlap[which(df$Overlap==TRUE)-1]=TRUE
df$Overlap[which(is.na(df$Overlap))]=FALSE

> df
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Class [2]
   Class   Min   Max Overlap
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
 1 A       100   200 FALSE  
 2 A       200   210 FALSE  
 3 A       210   310 FALSE  
 4 A       500   630 TRUE   
 5 A       510   530 TRUE   
 6 A       705   800 FALSE  
 7 B       100   200 FALSE  
 8 B       200   210 FALSE  
 9 B       210   310 FALSE  
10 B       500   630 TRUE   
11 B       510   530 TRUE   
12 B       705   800 FALSE
```

This code assumes your values are in ascending order, as it only checks with the previous row.

**edit**
Not the prettiest but works.

```
df_foo$Class=as.character.factor(df_foo$Class)
df_foo=as.data.frame(df_foo)
df_foo$Overlap=rep("FALSE",nrow(df_foo))
for (i in 1:nrow(df_foo)){
  aux=FALSE
  class=df_foo$Class[i]
  df=df_foo[-i,]%>%filter(.,Class==class)
  for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (df_foo[i,"Min"]<df[j,"Max"] & df_foo[i,"Max"] > df[j,"Min"]){
      aux=TRUE
    }
  }
  df_foo[i,"Overlap"]=aux
}


> df_foo
   Class Min Max Overlap
1      A 500 630    TRUE
2      A 100 200   FALSE
3      B 100 200   FALSE
4      A 210 310   FALSE
5      A 200 210   FALSE
6      B 210 310   FALSE
7      A 510 530    TRUE
8      B 200 210   FALSE
9      A 705 800   FALSE
10     B 500 630    TRUE
11     B 510 530    TRUE
12     B 705 800   FALSE
```

There must be a way to do it with `dplyr` but I could not figure it out. What is going on is that it loops through each row of `df_foo`; it generates a `dataframe` with all other rows of the same group and compares if there is any overlap (`min<max` and `max<min`)

Comment: Thank you I should have been more clear but in my actual dataset all values are mixed up and do not follow either an ascending or descending order

Comment: can there be more than one overlap? if not, just rearrange in ascending order by `Class` and the code is good to go. If not, it should clearly be changed.

Comment: There could be more than one overlap. I have edited the example to show how the data is mixed up. Thanks for your help!